# PrimeFaces splitButton: immediate="true" does not seem to work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Sidenote: It works with Command-Buttons.

**What I Have:**

A simple form where name and address from a customer are entered. In a data-table below, each row contained (in the working version) the following fields:

- Name of the customer
- A Command-Button which redirects to another page and shows the customers orders (This worked using  `<p: commandButton immediate="true">`)
- Another Command-Button which displayed the past orders.
- Another Command-Button which was responsible for updating customer-data.

Since I didn't want to have three Command-Buttons in each row I decided to use a Split-Button.

**Problem:**

```
<p:splitButton immediate="true">
```

The form asks me to fill the missing data (name and address) which are set to `required="true`.

**Question:** 
As far as I understand the attribute `immediate="true` is used to overcome this issue. So what am I missing ?

**Code:**

```
<h:form>
<p:growl id="growl" sticky="false" life="3500" showDetail="false"/>

<h:panelGrid id="customer_grid" columns="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">

    <h:outputLabel id="label" for="name" value="Kunde:" style="font-weight:bold"/>             
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{customerController.customer.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name eingeben!"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="address" value="Adresse:" style="font-weight: bold" />
    <p:inputText id="address" value ="#{customerController.customer.address}" required="true" requiredMessage="Adresse eingeben!"/>

    <p:commandButton  action = "#{customerController.createCustomer}" value="Speichern" style="margin-right:10px" 
                      actionListener="#{growlController.saveMessage}" ajax="true" 
                      onclick="PF('blockUIWidget').block()" oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock()" styleClass="save-button"/>

    <p:commandButton onclick="history.back(); return false;" value="Abbrechen" ajax="true"/>

    <pe:blockUI widgetVar="blockUIWidget">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:graphicImage id="loader" name="images/ajax-loader.gif" style="margin-right: 12px; vertical-align: middle;" rendered="true"/>
            <h:outputText value="Please wait..." style="white-space: nowrap;"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </pe:blockUI>
</h:panelGrid>

<br/>
<br/>

<p:dataTable var="customer" value="#{customerController.allCustomers}" resizableColumns="true" tableStyle="width: auto"
             rendered="#{not empty customerController.allCustomers}">

    <p:column headerText="customer" style="width: 300px">
        <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:splitButton value="current order" action="#{userController.setup(customer, 'lastOrder')}" immediate="true">
            <p:menuitem value="old orders" action="#{userController.setup(customer, 'oldOrders')}" immediate="true"/>
            <p:menuitem value="edit" action="#{userController.setup(customer, 'update')}" immediate="true"/>
        </p:splitButton>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

**EDIT:**

According to the comment of BalusC I've put the two parts in separate forms.
Effect: The message to fill out the above form does not show up, but the redirect is not happening either.

**EDIT2:**

The purpose of the method `userController.setup(customer, 'String')` is basically to inject the customer who is represented for each row. The String is returned for redirecting purposes which are set in the faces-config.xml and as I said: It works when I use Command-Buttons instead.

CODE:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable{

@Inject
private Customer customer;

@EJB
private CustomerService customerService;

public UserController(){

}

public List<Item> getItems(){
    return customerService.getItems(customer);
}

public Ordery getCurrentOrder(){
    return customerService.getCurrentOrder(customer);
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public CustomerService getCustomerService() {
    return customerService;
}

public void setCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
    this.customerService = customerService;
}

public String setup(Customer customer, String nav){
    this.customer = customer;
    return nav;
}

public void update(){
    customerService.update(customer);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you placing different forms inside one and same `<h:form>` in first place? Moreover, using `immediate="true"` should not be necessary anymore in JSF 2.x thanks to ajax support which enables you to process only a specific part of the form.

Comment: 1.) Because I am quite a noob. 2.) I've just put it in two separate forms. Now the message, that the fields are required does not show up, yet the redirect does not happen.

Comment: Please, put the code of `setup` method and we'll be able to help you better.